# Is there a way to reliably set rooms on fire?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I have an achievement that requires setting fire to... sorry, *extinguishing* a certain number of fires. I tend to just rush a room until I've *extinguished* the requisite number of fires. However this takes a long time - sometimes I get radroach or molerat infestations.

Is there a way to avoid these, and cause more fires to happen?

Comment: 1) Name one of your dwellers Kalina. 2) Assign her to the room. 3) ??? 4) Achievement get!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**The best way to cause a fire or radroach infestation is to rush a room several times in a row.** Beyond that, there's no way to ensure you always one of those events vs. the other event.

For reference:

- Having an active radio room increases the frequency of deathclaw and raider attacks.
- Opening your vault door increases the frequency of deathclaw and molerat attacks.
- Building rooms increases the frequency of molerat attacks.

Comment: This is the first time I've heard the molerat bit, is there any evidence to this?

Comment: From the [release notes](http://www.bethblog.com/2015/08/13/fallout-shelter-a-better-life-underground-and-on-android/): "Overseers should be on the lookout for new threats to their Vault Dwellers. Some Vaults have reported attacks by burrowing Mole Rats and enraged Deathclaws – likely attracted by the sound of new construction."

Comment: Well that is interesting, and certainly explains why I don't deal with molerats yet. I've more or less stopped all construction/breeding until I get all of my dwellers to have rusty laser pistols or better, haha.

Answer (score 1):

You can build a room isolated from the rest of your shelter to do repeat rush.

If you do not get a fire, run your dweller out of the room and wait for the incident to die down on its own.  Because it is isolated, it'll just end without you needing to end it.

This method can prevent excess happiness loss in rush failures.

Comment: Does it still count towards the achievement?

Comment: No.  If the fire dies by itself you didn't put it out.  It went out on its own.

Answer (score 1):

Rush a room that is not touching dirt.

You won't get molerat attacks, which means getting a fire is more probable.

Answer (score 0):

I needed a quest for extinguishing 21 vault fires so I put all my top leveled and most powerful dwellers in a Nuka Cola Station and I got fires 100% of the time. I don't know why this is but it's the method that seemed to work so I won't question it.. (Keep in mind it was 6 dwellers all with almost maxed special but their levels ranged from 11 to 48.) It could be that a single stat is high in the room so that only fire is possible or that the MIRV cant fire in the vault. It's also possible that the weapons do so much damage in total that it eliminates the ability for pests to enter. I don't know but it works.